# Samsung Galaxy s3 Battery life

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery-life, battery, screen, standby

How long should a Galaxy S3 battery last?
My phone is brand new and today it was on standby for most of the day (it dropped 10% while being on standby for 3hrs), I only used the internet for about an hour and recieved one phone call. And my phone is almost dead!
I have gps and bluetooth disabled, the screen as dim as it will go and don't have any instant notifications. I also don't have any new apps on the phone yet.
My battery life says:
screen 41%
Adroid System 19%
Adroid OS 12%
Device Idle 6%
Cell Standby 6%
Internet 4%
Maps 3%
Phone 3%
Messaging 2%
Could I have a faulty battery?

Comment: Were you in an area with LTE service?

Comment: I've just added the `battery-life` tag to your question. You might want to check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info) for some basic background, info, and links. Also, [its most frequented questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life?sort=frequent) might prove helpful while waiting for a good answer here. If anything from those sources helped improve your situation, please don't forget to let us know here :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an AT&T Galaxy SIII.  I use BetterBatteryStats when I have battery issues.  Lately I've been having problems with the calendar sync service keeping the phone awake.  I cleared its data and resynced from scratch, and that helped, but a few hours ago I created a new calendar, and now it's going bonkers again.

Anyway, the best I've been able to get is about 3% per hour when not being actively used.  I might have seen 2.5% one time, but that was a few months ago.  Typically though, especially with this calendar sync problem, I see 4.5% per hour or worse.

So if your question is, "How long should the battery last?" my best answer from my experience is about 24-28 hours, considering an average 3% per hour drain while idle, and light usage.  If you make a few long phone calls, that will, of course, drain it much faster.

But any apps that go haywire and cause excess wakelocks will wreck it quick.  I love the freedom of Android compared to iOS, but I really want more control over apps background behavior.  Android 4.3 may provide this, but who knows if the SIII will ever get it.